# Problems with select in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem with a select in postgres. Create a db with a new user but in pg admin when applying a query within the program it returns me

```
ERROR: permission denied for table users
```

Apply a query to give privileges with:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO someuser;
```

as well as a query to give privileges to the table but nothing: /

Comment: How did you create the table? Which user were you logged in as when you did that? How did you create the `someuser`? What user are you using for the pgadmin connection?

Comment: hello, i used create role ricardo with login password 'password'; and then alter role to create db

Comment: In `psql` do `\dp users` and add the results as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver sorry, i did not undertand

Comment: Use the `psql` command line program that ships with Postgres and connect to the server with it and issue the command `\dp users`. Add the result returned as update to your question. In pgAdmin4 that would be: 1) Right click on table name 2) Click on properties 3) Select Security tab.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver but i didnt work, while i was adding the user privileges on pgadmin the same error came up.

Comment: The point was to see what privileges are on the table already.  Also what user are you logging into pgAdmin as? Add answers as update to your question.